# Retrieving PCDATA with pugixml and xpath

Tags: c++, xml, xpath

I spent the last week reading and re-reading the pugixml documentation and I can find no method of retrieving the PCDATA with xpath.

Please explain would I pull the text from title:

```
<html><head><title>Hello!</title></head></html>
```

Edit: corrected CData to PCData

Answer (score 0):

> Please explain would I pull the text from title:
>
> ```
> <html><head><title>Hello!</title></head></html>
> ```

One XPath expression that selects this text node is:

```
/*/head/title/text()
```

If just the string value is wanted (and not the text node), use:

```
string(/*/head/title)
```